# Android Studio Build Flavor organizing via Git

Tags: android, git, android-studio, android-build-flavors

Following situation.
We work on an Android Project with several Build Flavors as releases. In the moment it's organized like this
Build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
   original{
    applicationId =com.example.original
   }
   var1{
   applicationId =com.example.var1
   }
   var2{
   applicationId =com.example.var2
   }
}
...
```

folder structure

`main
-java
--com.example
---classA
original
-java
--com.example
---classB (original)
---classC (original)
var1
-java
--com.example
---classB (new)
---classC (original)
var2
-java
--com.example
---classB (original)
---classC (new)`

the Problem now is that var2 has a copy of classB and var1 has a copy of classC. So whenever i do a change to one of the original classes I have to copy that file in every flavor that uses the original class. But it looks like that this is the way I have to do it for buildflavors.

So I was thinking if I could solve this problem by using Git and several release branches. Maybe with a script and cherrypicking. But I'm not very confident with git. So my idea of the git structure was like this.

[git idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3ia9.png)

So my question now is if it would make sense to use Git for that purpose. If yes how would a script for git look like. Or is there a better way to solve that problem

Comment: I'm not sure the current situation u described is possible. You can't have classB in both original and var1...

Comment: Yes it is cause with buildflavors it just ignores the other flavors for that build. So for example if I build flavor var1 it ignores flavor original and flavor var2